# Determing if string has all unique characters

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, char

How can I do this without using arrays?
I have this implementation, but I need to do it without using arrays, bit operations and any other C/C++ libraries.

```
bool IsCharDuplication(string s) {
  bool result = false;
  bool controlArray[256];
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int val = s[i];
    if (controlArray[val] == true) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
    controlArray[val] = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: nope, that was 10 years ago i am doing homework:) just a tricky c++ question finding alternative ways.

Comment: Thanks, just curious about the interesting restrictions.

Comment: You can also speed things up every so often if you do a check for the character maps number of values. `s.length() > 128` for ascii or even Unicode (probably unrealistic to check) if you know what version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two nested loop:

```
bool IsCharDuplication(string s)
{   
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
    for (int j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++) 
      if (s[i] == s[j])
        return true;   
 return false;
}
```

***Note:*** your algorithm has time of O(N), But my solution has time of O(N^2).

Answer (score 5):

You can do better than the O(N^2) algorithm suggested in the other answer.

For example, you can Quick-sort or Merge-sort the String in O(NlogN) and than do a single pass over the sorted String to determine if there are any duplicates in O(N). There total time complexity will be O(NlogN).

```
bool IsCharDuplication (string s)
{
  string s2 = sort(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length () - 1; i++)
    if (s2[i] == s2[i+1])
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

I didn't include the code for sorting the string, but you can find such code easily and write your own `sort` method (since you are not allowed to use C/C++ libraries).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hash table (or hash set) to get O(n) complexity. The following implenetation uses bitwise operations where each bit correspond to each char in the alphabet.

```
/**
* Works for 0-127 ASCII string. Assuming, int is 16 bit.
**/
int isduplicate(const char* str){
    int hash[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    while(*str){ 
        int pos=*str;
        if(hash[pos/16]&(1<<(pos%16)))
            return 1;
        hash[pos/16]|=(1<<(pos%16)); 
        str++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With this method if the int is 64 bit, you will only need 2 of them (for 0-127). If you know that your string will only have a-z and A-Z, you will need 2 32 bit int or 1 64 bit int :)

Comment: The OP asked to do this `without using arrays, bit operations`. While your solution uses a smaller array, it still uses an array and bit operations.

Comment: Humm, I did not see the bit operation part, sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

```
// ASCII assumed over unicode
// O(n) algorithm
// O(1) space
bool isUnique(string s) {
    // cannot exceed number of unique characters
    if (s.length() > 256) return false;
    bool checker[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int val = s.at(i);
        if (checker[val] == true)
            return false;
        checker[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what `        int val = s.at(i);` exactly does?

Comment: @Alex it returns the character of the string at index i, then casts that into an integer. You can think of this as the hash key into checker, since each character will have it's own unique integer.